# How to use Firebase functions to extract variable from online html?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to add function that returns a value of a variable from online HTML to my android app.

For example: In [www.fictiveURL.com](http://www.fictiveURL.com) there is an HTML that part of him is:

```
<span id="dailyTimes">
<div id="times1">
6:41<br>8:57<br>9:33<br>12:25<br>12:55<br>18:13</div>
<div id="times2">
6:58<br>8:57<br>9:33<br>12:26<br>12:56<br>18:11</div>
```

I wrote that JS function to extract the variable I need:

```js
function get() {
    var time = document.getElementById("times1");
    return time.querySelector("br:nth-child(5)").nextSibling.nodeValue;
}
```

So, how can I put that JS function in Firebase? I mean, what should I do to enable my JS do functions on third-party html?

This is my first project that I'm trying using Firebase so I know nothing about how to work with it.

Comment: It sounds like you want to build what is known as a web scraper. Since Cloud Functions are essentially just managed pieces of Node.js code, I'd recommend looking at some of these search results: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+build+a+web+scraper+in+node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to setup your Function on Firebase Functions would be to firstly follow the [get started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) guide and verify that all of the prerequisite steps are completed (1 through 3) are completed.

You will then be able to [import the required modules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app) and proceed in [adding your function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions#write_functions_in_multiple_files) to the index.js file.

As mentioned by Frank, the Firebase Functions utilizes Node.js so importing your code should not be difficult.

Once you are satisfied with the results of testing the Firebase Function you can go ahead and deploy the function using:

```
    $ firebase deploy --only functions
```

Then you can call the function either directly from your [Firebase app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) through setting up a [callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function):

```
exports.[function-name] = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
});
```

Or you can call it with a [HTTP request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) through setting up the function in the following manner:

```
exports.[function-name] = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // ...
});
```